# Exibir chamada de API no visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin-forms

Estou iniciando na programação usando Xamarin forms e desenvolvendo primeira chamada usando uma API básica, quero ver se a chamada ao Endpoint está correta e retorno do mesmo, existe alguma tela no Visual Studio 2019 para exibir o que está sendo enviado e o retorno?

Abaixo o código que estou iniciando os testes.

```
public async void ExecuteLoginAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var user = new User();

        user.UserEmail = email.Text;
        user.UserPassword = password.Text;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.UserEmail) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.UserPassword))
        {
            await DisplayAlert("", "Verifique seu e-mail e senha e tente novamente", "OK");
        }

        try
        {
           var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var uri = new Uri("https://teste/appLogin");
            var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
            var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content);

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new Exception("Erro");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

A tela de debug não mostra a requisição e nem a resposta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Um debugger não serve?

Comment: O debug não mostra as requisições e respostas de chamado a API / JSON

Comment: Mas vai mostrar o resultado que está na variável `response` e os dados da requisição também estão nas outras variáveis

Comment: @Costamilam eu adicionei uma imagem da tela de debug, veja que não tem informação da requisição e nem da resposta

Comment: Esse debugger parece estranho, estava imaginando algo assim: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2016/07/image_thumb387.png (apenas um exemplo), onde você consegue ver as variáveis e seus valores, isso aí parece só um console de saída, ou então faltou criar um ponto de pausa